# How to move users' data from a separate partition on one drive to another drive and remove the original users' data partition?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ntfs, user-folders

Simplifying, my old drive has four partitions; we are going to speak about first two (which "belong" to Windows; the remaining two "belong" to Linux). Let's call the first two partitions C: and D:; they are NTFS. Partition C: contains the Windows 10 system and programs, and D: contains users' data in users' folders: we have directories D:\Jack, D:\Jane, D:\Sally, and subdirectories D:\Jack\Downloads, D:\Jack\Documents, D:\Jack\Favorites, ... that I could move easily to D: by changing the location of the corresponding subdirs of C:\Users in file properties.  Hidden, system, and admin subdirectories and files in C:\Users stay where they originally were (namely, in C:\Users).

The goal of moving was (and is) to store users' data separately from the system, programs, and auxiliary admin data.  Such a scheme eases backups, reinstallation, recovery from crashes, etc.

Two years after moving, I ran out of space on both partitions. The current partition C: is 80% full, and the current partition D: won't hold a large chunk of external users' data that logically belongs there. Now I bought a new large drive that I'd like to use for the the users' data only (with hidden/system/admin files from old C:\Users or without -- I don't care). The old D: partition should be gone, the old C: partition should be extended to the space freed by deleting old D:, and the new D: partition should be on the new secondary drive and contain the data from the old D: partition (either exhibiting the same structure as now, i.e., with hidden/system/admin files still in C:\users, or containing all of %Users%; I don't care about the difference).

How do I accomplish this such that Windows 10 is still usable after the change and the users won't feel too much difference except more space?

As available tools, I have Debian live with gnome (so, I believe, linux tools could work) and a Windows 10 installation image.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the short answer but here is the method to remove the users partition (D:) and extend the space available on the C: drive. The method is to use Disk Management.

1. Open Disk Management by opening Windows Search and typing 'Create and Format Hard Disk Partitions'
2. Right click on the partition of the larger drive you want to use and click 'Change Drive Letter and Paths' and follow the prompts to assign a letter.
3. Copy all your data from D: to the new large drive.
4. Right-Click on D: and click Delete Volume and follow the prompts if there are any. **DO THIS ONLY AFTER COPYING ALL DATA TO THE LARGER DRIVE!!**
5. Right click on the new, large drive and assign the letter D.

Technically you just did what you wanted by extending C: and deleting D: although this isn't recommended because changing anything related to your Windows account's home folder can render the account unusable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly safer version of SP Tutors answer:

- attach new disk alongside original. initilise, create partition and format as `Z:`
- reboot into safe mode (this prevents so many potential issues)
- copy directories from `D:` to `Z:`
- In disk management console - change `D:` drive's letter to `T:`. Then change `Z:` to `D:` (ie you can undo this change)
- Reboot
- If alls well, proceed with deleting `T:` partition (ie the old `D:` drive) and expanding `C:`. Any issues go back to safe mode and switch the drive letters back.

> ... with hidden/system/admin files from old C:\Users or without -- I don't care

I recommend you leave those files on the C:, and ideally maintain a backup of that directory alongside the user data on the new data drive. (some apps might ignore the setting and default to the C: anyway, and those hidden/system/admin files contain all sorts of data/settings/defaults/templates from Windows and your installed applications etc that might be worth saving)

NOTE: If at all possible you should take an image of your `C:` before you start if your not confident you can recover the system.